# Is it possible to animate a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I tried various samples regarding animation of fragments, but nothing happens so is DialogFragment not a "proper" fragment? Or am I missing something here?

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();                                      
InfoDialogFragment newFragment = InfoDialogFragment.newInstance();
newFragment.setAsset(mainShow, c,backgroundDrawable);
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.grow_in, R.anim.fadeout);
ft.add(newFragment, "dialog");
ft.commit();
...
public class InfoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
```