# EditText not tinted in Accent color on lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm Software Engineering student that just started learning android development a couple months ago during my spare time.

at the moment im making my first app while learning in the process and i ran into a problem.

I'm using a DialogFragment and for some reason the Accent color i use in my theme is overridden only in pre-lollipop devices (both emulator and physical).

you can notice that only the floating hint is tinted in lollipop.

[image: For Example:]

### my DialogFragment layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dialog_add_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_title_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/dialog_add_title_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_password_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/dialog_add_password_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/input_cancel"
        style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/input_confirm"
        style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### my values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorHighlight</item>

    <!-- Context Action Mode will Overlay Toolbar -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

</style>
```

i already tried several solutions to no avail:

1. overriding colorControlActivated and colorControlNormal - only changes floating hint tint
2. changing the tint programmatically, but that only changes the underline while not focused:

   Drawable background = InputTextLayout.getEditText().getBackground();
   DrawableCompat.setTint(background, yourColor);
   InputTextLayout.getEditText().setBackground(background);

using EditText alone, not wrapped in TextInputLayout, doesn't help either.

any ideas?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What version of the design support library are you using?

Comment: im using version 23.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a thorough search through the internet i stumbled upon a question here in stackoverflow regarding animating a DialogFragment - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129567/is-it-possible-to-animate-a-dialogfragment)

the answer in that link referred to a post by a Google Engineer saying:

> ...DialogFragment is **just a wrapper** around a Dialog to help manage its lifecycle.  Dialogs are top-level windows so their animations are window animations, just like when you use Dialog in all other situations.  You thus control the animations of dialogs through the **theme** or explicit window animation style you have set in its WindowManager.LayoutParams.

so i decided to check how to theme the DialogFragment
& found this guide by CodePath - [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-DialogFragment#styling-custom-dialog)

basically, in your App Theme, in order to override the Dialog Themes you have to add the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent...>
    ....

    <!-- this will override DialogFragment theme -->
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogFragmentTheme</item>
    <!-- this will override AlertDialog theme -->
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyAlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomAlertDialogTheme.Animation">
    ...
</style>

<style name="MyDialogFragmentTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    ...
</style>
```

in each of the theme you can override attributes like colorPrimary, colorAccent etc.

if using this method makes your DialogFragment appear without a title (it happend to me), then add the following to its style:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
```

### Bonus - adding animations

in order to add animations to either the AlertDialog or DialogFragment, write the following in its style:

```
<style name="MyDialogFragmentTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyDialogFragmentTheme.Animation</item>

</style>
```

then you need to create a style for the animation, for example:

```
<style name="MyDialogFragmentTheme.Animation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/dialog_slide_in_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/dialog_slide_out_down</item>
        <item name="android:interpolator">@android:interpolator/anticipate</item>
</style>
```

**there's more info in the CodePath guide linked above.**

note that this all takes place in values/styles.xml

hope this helps other people.